# Repair corrupted tar.gz file

Tags: data-recovery, disk, gzip

Alright so I'm trying to extract a Google Takeout archive, extension is `tar.gz` and the file command says `gzip` compressed data. The archive is split into 11 `tar.gz` files.

The 6th `tar.gz` file is experiencing an `IO error` when I try to access it. I tried using `cat` to combine them but it seems like it hangs midway.

How would I go upon repairing or salvaging anything from this archive?

---

I'm copying the file for example, it'll copy about 800MBs and then hang or it stops and says an IO error occurred.

I tried repairing the filesystem from the Disks app and it said it was successful but when I ran the check it said it was undamaged.

Comment: What does `file 6th.tar.gz` say? IO error might be disk issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

> Well if I'm copying the file for example, it'll copy about 800MBs and then hang or it stops and says an IO error occurred.

**Your disk (or whatever drive) is faulty.**

---

From question:

> How would I go upon repairing or salvaging anything from this archive?

**There is no straightforward way of such repair possible, sadly.**

---

There might be, however, several utilities online able to maybe cope with very minor corruption, though. **The only thing to recommend here is to replace your faulty drive first.**

Comment: Any recommendation of such utilities to fix minor issues, i am pretty sure my tar file has not a lot of missing data it might have only a few bits corrupted